# agregar URL para llamar a un WebService para realizar una busqueda en TiempoReal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webservice

Tengo el siguiente problema le hago mantenimiento a un proyecto donde quiero traer datos desde otro maquina de desarrollo por medio de WebService.
Realizo una consulta en tiempo real a nivel local (localhost) y funciona, también funciona atreves de un  dominio sitio host que ya existía allí

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo pero utilizando la IP de mi otra maquina de desarrollo

este es el código JavaScript para realizar la Búsqueda

```
function doneTypingSearch() {
    $('.producto').autocomplete({        
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://222.22.22.222/wsinterfaz/Rest/PublicService.svc/FindProducts",
                type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                crossOrigin: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Search: request.term,
                    ApiKey:"XXXXX77777",// Maquina de donde quiero que funcione
                    //ApiKey:"12345ABCDEXXX",// localhost EL QUE INCORPORE
                    //ApiKey:"ConveniosDes",// Dominio clienteconve.lcl.com.ve QUE YA EXISTIA
                    Count: 100,
                    StartIndex: 0,
                    StoreId: "A001"
                }),
                success: function( data ) {
           
                    var res = data;
            
                    //alert(data.Products.length);
                    var availableTags = [];
           
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
                        var principio = data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient != "" ? " - " + data.Products[i].ActiveIngredient : "";
                        var precio = data.Products[i].LastFullPrice != 0 ? " Precio: "+ (data.Products[i].LastFullPrice).toFixed(2) : "";
                        var opt = data.Products[i].Description + principio + precio;
                        availableTags.push({ label: opt, id: data.Products[i].Id, indice: i });
                    }
                     
                    
                    response( availableTags );
                },

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            desbloquearGuardar();
            var sapCode = ui.item.id;
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $($(this).nextAll("input[type=hidden]")).val(sapCode || "");
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }, function () {
    }, 300);
}
```

Este es el archivo Json para la clave ApiKey para poder obtener esos Datos

```
{
    "Authorizations": [
        { 
            "Key": "ConveniosDes",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "clienteconve.lcl.com.ve",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "12345ABCDEXXX",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "localhost",
                "CanViewPrices": true,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        },
        { 
            "Key": "XXXXX77777",
            "Value": {
                "Kind": 1,
                "Content": "111.11.11.111:8080",
                "CanViewPrices": false,
                "StoreId": "A001"
            }
        }
        
    ]
}
```

En el ultima autorización es donde quiero que se visualice pero no estoy seguro de si estoy colocando bien en el Content el valor, cuando copio 111.11.11.111:8080 y lo pego en el navegador desde otra maquina me abre el proyecto pero no funciona la búsqueda para traer datos

la que dice localhost la establecí y funciona perfectamente anexo imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la ultima donde hago el llamado desde otra maquina- no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria su apoyo para este problema

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas publicar (ya sea IIS u otro proveedor) el proyecto que contiene el WebService en la máquina que deseas utilizar como servidor, así podrás consultarlo en la IP de tu otra máquina de desarrollo

Comment: Eso es lo que hice esta publicado en IIS y la dirección es 111.11.11.111:8080 y el proyecto levanta perfecto, pero no funciona la búsqueda. a nivel local de desarrollo de la dirección 222.22.22.222 si funciona pero en esta que intento incorporar no

Comment: Activa la opción de visualizar errores en tu proyecto y revisa si no te envía alguno. Además, yo te recomendaría que usarás las IP's que te da por default IIS, luego por eso no se cargan correctamente los datos.

Comment: No logro que funcione a nivel local desde la solution en mi otra maquina de desarrollo desde la solution, tuve que crear una nueva url y publicarlo iis y almacenarlo allí